# Use C++ dll and typedef in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, typedef

I'm doing a C# program which need to call a DLL created by C++. But I get an error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)'" when run it.

It is the  string pass to "char *pcAddrs" issue? Thank in advance.

C++ DLL info

```
typedef struct CommIfInfo
{
    char *pcAddrs;
    long lPortNo;
    long lRetry;
    long lSendTimeOut;
    long lCommSide;
    long lMode;
    long lKind;
} COMMIF_INFO;

//Function need to call.
int Open( COMMIF_INFO *pInfo )
```

Code in C#

```
    // DLL import
    [DllImport("Open-IF.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern int Open(COMMIFINFO info);

    // Structure
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]        
    public struct COMMIFINFO
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] public string ip;
        public int PortNo;
        public int Retry;
        public int SendTimeOut;
        public int CommSide;
        public int Mode;
        public int Kind;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _ip = "192.168.1.1";
        COMMIFINFO info = new COMMIFINF();
        info.ip =  _ip;
        info.Kind = 1;

        int ErrCode = Open(info);
    }
```

Comment: Your calling convention is wrong (CallingConvention.StdCall).  StdCall is windows calling convention and not c language.  Use CallingConvention.Cdecl

Comment: "_An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format_" Well, that pretty much sounds like you have x86/x64 (32-bit vs. 64 bit) mismatch. Either your program runs as 64-bit process and Open-IF.dll is a 32-bit DLL, or vice versa. So, first figure out whether Open-IF.dll is a 32-bit or 64-bit DLL. Then set the project settings for your C# program so that it targets the same "bitness" as the DLL...

Comment: Hi jdweng, I still get the same error after i change to "CallingConvention.Cdecl"

Comment: Hi MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, the dll is 32-bit, i need change the platform target from any CPU to x86 in c#?

Comment: Hi MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace, thank for the advice, no error after I tick the "Prefer 32-bit" in setting. now program is working. thank you very much